# Can I set a premium for a $20 minimum on a recurring contribution, but $80 for a one-time contribution?

Tags: contribution-page, premiums

It seems like premiums only work on the minimum amount, without regard for other settings.  Is there a way to get around this?  I see the [EFF](https://supporters.eff.org/donate/join-eff-4) has this option, but their contribution page seems not to be generated by CiviCRM anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this question and we have solved a similar problem a few years ago, i.e. we want to count the total value of recurring contributions (e.g. a $10 recurring should count as much as a $120 one time).

What we do is to rewrite the function used for computing the premium amount. The javascript is in `templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/PremiumBlock.tpl` (copied in a custom extension).

Simply adding the following to the function `get_amount` do the trick :

```
var isrecur = $('.is_recur_radio-section input:checked').val();
if (isrecur == 1) amount = amount * 12;
```

I suppose it's possible to add some more complex logic.

The fact that we need to update a core template file is not ideal for maintenance but it's a rather small change so it's easy to keep track of it and re-apply the change when we upgrade CiviCRM.

**EDIT** 2021-03-22

The solution above is not enough: there is validation in `CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php` that require adjustment.